# Exact word when we throw a rope in english

Tags: meaning, british-english

What's the exact word for throwing a fish hook or a rope whose one end we are holding.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fishing it is [***cast***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cast) and you ***throw*** a rope and throw or cast a line

Comment: Sailors may cast *lines*, which are in fact ropes. (Lines may also be thrown.)

Comment: Right - I agree. Updated

Answer (score 2):

If you mean this sort of thing with a fishing rod

[image: casting a fishing line]

then it's ***casting***. Ropes or lines are ***thrown.***

[Image reference](http://flyfishing.thefuntimesguide.com/2009/02/fly_rod_casting.php)

Comment: As I already said without the pretty pic, no!

Comment: @mplungjan I like pictures :-) And it illustrates the answer and illuminates the question, where "throwing a fish hook" is not particularly clear.

Comment: Ok, just wondering...